# Can I use pk from another model in RetrieveAPIView. Is this a bad practice?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am working on an RetrieveAPIView api in which I want to pass the id of  college and it will return all students who are currently studying there, but I am using Modelserializer of student model. code is in college app. I am in trouble is this a bad practice?

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from student.views import StudentView

path('studentdetails/<int:college_id>/', views.StudentView.as_view())
```

my serializer.py

```
from student.models import Student

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'rollno')
```

my views.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework import serializers
from student.serializer import StudentSerializer
from student.models import Student
from .models import College 

class StudentView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            college_id=College.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('college_id'))
            data=myfunction(id=college_id)
            response_data=self.get_serializer(data, many=True)
            return Response({"data": response_data.data})
         except College.DoesNotExist:
             raise serializers.ValidationError(_("College Does Not exists"))
```

Comment: The `RetrieveAPIView` supposed to return only One result, else it will raise an error. I would recommend using a filter in your case.,

Comment: You can use `ListAPIView` for that.

Comment: @JPG filter where? or Should I use ListAPIView?

Answer (score 0):

**RetrieveAPIView** Used for read-only endpoints to represent a single model instance.

so try to user **ListAPIView**

Try this

Assuming that you have college foreign key in **student** model

```
from rest_framework import generics

class StudentView(generics.ListAPIView):

   queryset = Student.objects.all()
   serializer_class = StudentSerializer

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            college_id=College.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('college_id'))
            students = self.queryset.filter(college=college_id)
            response_data=self.get_serializer(students, many=True)
            return Response(
               {
                 "data": response_data.data
               }
           )

         except College.DoesNotExist:
             raise serializers.ValidationError(_("College Does Not exists"))
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use ListAPIView instead of RetrieveAPIView and use filtering. Change get_queryset method or add own filter.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/